# How to make assignment to my variable?

Tags: linux, bash, date

I want to generate 5 files having last five days as a datestamp in the file name.
How do I capture the date command as shown into my variable `FILE_DATE`?

```
for i in {1..5};
do 
#FILE_DATE=$(date --date="$i days ago" + "%m%d%Y")  # Yields Try 'date --help' for more information
#FILE_DATE=(date --date="$i days ago" + "%m%d%Y")   # Yields Foobardate
#FILE_DATE=`date --date="$i days ago" + "%m%d%Y"`   # Yields Try 'date --help' for more information
#FILE_DATE="date --date="$i days ago" + "%m%d%Y""   # Yields days command not found

echo "Foobar$FILE_DATE"
done
```

**Desired Output**

Foobar07172017

Foobar07162017

Foobar07152017

Foobar07142017

Foobar07132017

Comment: Using  GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you using?  This worked for me on CentOS 7 but I got a different error than you without the quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
for i in {1..5}; do
file_date=$(date --date="$i days ago" "+ %m%d%Y") # "+ %m%d%Y" Creates a space before the date
echo "Foobar${file_date:1}" # Removes space before the date
done
```

**OR**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
for i in {1..5}; do
file_date=$(date --date="$i days ago" "+%m%d%Y")
echo "Foobar$file_date"
done
```

Both will produce the desired result:

```
[root@JBLGSMR002 ~]# ./test.sh
Foobar07172017
Foobar07162017
Foobar07152017
Foobar07142017
Foobar07132017
```

Comment: Using  GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Does it work for you if you include the `+` in your quotes like I have in my script?

Comment: Ah that is it. I put the + inside the quotes and it works.

Comment: No problem.  My script was creating a space before the date for some reason so it was producing a bad output (`Foobar 07172017`).  I've made an edit to my answer to correct this.